# VB.Net send decimal udp

Tags: vb.net, udp, decimal, ascii

I am trying to send a single byte to a PIC from a computer (Note: the pic only accepts a single byte else it will only accept the first byte of the data send)

This shouldn't be much of a problem because I only want to manage a total of 8 LEDS so I only need it to go from 0 to 255 but I am having issues achieving this. 
If I try to send the value 1 to the pic my program sends 31 if I try to send 5 it sends 35 If I try to send 255 it sends 3**2**3**5**3**5** so for every single digit I try to send it adds a 3 in front of it. I am using the following code to determine the value and to send it:

```
        Dim t As Integer = 0
    Dim result As Integer = 0
    For Each chk As CheckBox In GroupBox1.Controls
        If chk.Checked = True Then
            result = result + 2 ^ t
        End If
        t = t + 1
    Next
    publisher.Connect(IPTo, PortTo)
    Dim sendbytes() As Byte = ASCII.GetBytes(result)
    publisher.Send(sendbytes, sendbytes.Length)
```

I think the issue is with the convert to ASCII.

I also try to receive the inputs from the PIC to my pc for this I have the following script inside a timer:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Try
            Dim ep As IPEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0)
            Dim rcvbytes() As Byte = subscriber.Receive(ep)

            Dim translate As String
            translate = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(rcvbytes, 0)

            TBRcv.Text = translate
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: As an aside, if you set `Option Explicit On` and `Option Infer Off`, you'd see why this code doesn't work.

Comment: If you're having issues receiving your data, make sure you've receive *all* of the bytes you sent. If that tip doesn't help; it's better to ask a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASCII.GetBytes expects a string (encoded in ASCII). Giving it an Int32 doesn't make sense.

Check out [System.BitConverter.GetBytes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4.aspx) and [System.BitConverter.ToInt32()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32.aspx) (for the receiving end)

So the only change you'd need to make is:

```
Dim sendbytes() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(result)
```

Further discussion:
What has happened is that your result (let's say 5), is first converted to string (now it's "5"), then ASCII.GetBytes will now return a byte array with a single value 0x35, because Asc("5") is 0x35.

Comment: Okay with this I am getting some good data. But this means I also need to have a converter in the receiving part which is going to be a bit of a issue but I think I will be able to manage

Comment: `Asc()` converts a single character. `ASCII.GetChars()` returns many characters.

I wouldn't know where to begin with your malformed-packed error. I've used this method to send many different types of data over a UDP connection without issue.

Comment: Well it works for most the part but as soon as the value goes above the 63 I get this error. Also the data send starts at 01000000 shouldn't it start at just 01?

Comment: No. When converting integers to byte arrays, the order of the bytes may change. But the GetBytes() and ToInt32() methods will both understand the conversion.

Comment: What also might be happening, is you're sending 'variable' length data. You either need to encode your messages so that the length of the bytes is always the same, or send one byte to instruct the receiver how many butes to expect. Often times the receiver hasn't got the "whole message".

Comment: Right I got it working. Also the receiving end works way better then it did before (before it skipped some values and printed something else) you have my gratitude! Ooh great thanks for the other reply about setting the byte size. This stopped the errors and made it exactly like how I wanted. Thanks so much!

Comment: Somehow I can send perfectly fine right now but now I am having issues receiving the data. Could you please help me out once more? I edited the original post with the receiving code.

Answer (score 1):

The ASCII value of the character `1` is 0x31, etc.  For reference :

[image]